# Последовательная конкатенация каждого элемента из одного списка с каждым элементом другого cписка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

никак не могу понять как выполнить задачу на python без сторонних библиотек.
Есть два списка:

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

По итогу нужно получить list3 вида ['Aa', 'Ba', 'Ca', ... , 'Ab', 'Bb', 'Cb', ... , 'Ac', 'Bc', 'Cc', ... ]

Понимаю, что нужно брать первый элемент из list2[0] и конкатенировать его с каждым элементом в list2 и сохранять в list3 и тд, но реализация хромает.
Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: А где та реализация, которая хромает?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваш код, и напишите что с ним не так.

Comment: Стандартные модули (например, itertools) Python считаются сторонними?

Comment: print(list([i+j for i in list1] for j in list2))

Comment: @АлексейБелкин, в вашем случае получается список списков, а в условии вроде один единый список надо.

Comment: @Андрюха, пожалуйста:   **print(list(i+j for i in list1 for j in list2))**

Comment: @АлексейБелкин, не, надо просто список, в вашем первоначальном решении получается `[[...],[...],[...]...]`, а не один список `[...]`. Не знаю, важно ли это для автора вопроса.

Comment: @АлексейБелкин Зачем делать `list` из генератора, если сразу можно использовать списковое сокращение `[...]`? )

Comment: @CrazyElf, =) Согласен. Я даже не знаю зачем здесь использовать list1 и list2 =) Можно и без них =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Типа так пойдет?

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list3=[]
for l2 in list2:
    for l1 in list1:
        list3.append(l1+l2)
print(list3)
```